# I'm having trouble running a tensorflow single shot detector and a Keras convnet in the same script. Getting this weird error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, object-detection

I am trying to build a program that can determine how many fingers I'm holding out on my hand. I have a single shot detector trained to draw a bounding box around my hand. The box is cropped out and fed to a convnet that is trained to determine how many fingers I'm holding out. They're both trained and work individually just fine. However, putting them both in the same script, nothing seems to work. I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("softmax_1/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 6), dtype=float32) 
is not an element of this graph.
```

I believe it has something to do with how I'm running two neural networks at the same time.

I tried writing `model._make_predict_function()` after I compiled the convnet model. Yet I got this:

```
File "/Users/spencerkraisler/Desktop/Hand_Sign_Classifier_2/hand_detector.py", line 66, in <module>
    pred = model.predict(box_image_exp)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1169, in predict
    steps=steps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 294, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2671, in _call
    session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2623, in _make_callable
    callable_fn = session._make_callable_from_options(callable_opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1471, in _make_callable_from_options
    return BaseSession._Callable(self, callable_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1425, in __init__
    session._session, options_ptr, status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Tensor conv2d_1_input:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession._Callable.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.BaseSession._Callable object at 0x136f91320>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1455, in __del__
    self._session._session, self._handle, status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: Session has been closed.
```

Code:

```
import cv2
import os
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras import metrics
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Softmax
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, ReLU
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from utils import detector_utils as detector_utils

# initializing convnet 
optimizer = Adam(lr=.01)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
num_classes = 6

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(ReLU())
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(ReLU())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(ReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Softmax())
model.load_weights("./convnet/classifier1.h5")
model.summary()
model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=optimizer,
        metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy])

# initializing ssd 
detection_graph, sess = detector_utils.load_inference_graph()

score_thresh = 0.2
im_width, im_height = 1280, 720
num_hands_detect = 1

def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='prefix')
    return graph

with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while(True):
            _, frame = cap.read()
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            boxes, scores = detector_utils.detect_objects(frame, detection_graph, sess)
            box_image = detector_utils.get_box_image(1, score_thresh, scores, boxes, im_width, im_height, frame)
            detector_utils.draw_box_on_image(1, score_thresh, scores, boxes, im_width, im_height, frame)
                        # this mean a hand was detected
            if box_image is not None:
                box_image = cv2.cvtColor(box_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                box_image = cv2.resize(box_image, (28, 28))
                box_image_exp = np.expand_dims(box_image, 2)
                box_image_exp = np.expand_dims(box_image_exp, 0)
                                # where the convnet makes its prediction
                pred = model.predict(box_image_exp)
                print(np.argmax(pred))

            cv2.imshow('frame', cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
            if box_image is not None:
                cv2.imshow('hand detection', box_image)
            else:
                cv2.imshow('hand detection', np.zeros((28, 28, 1)))

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This script is supposed to print out the convnet's predictions whenever the SSD detects my hand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root of the problem is that you create the Keras model under the default graph, but call it within the `detection_graph` scope. There are several workarounds possible. I would try to wrap the model creation code (from `model = Sequential()` to `model.compile(...)`) into a function and call the function under the `with detection_graph.as_default():`. Also, to be sure, set the Keras backend session to the session you create explicitly. So, like this:

```
import cv2
...
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as K
from utils import detector_utils as detector_utils

# initializing convnet 
optimizer = Adam(lr=.01)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
num_classes = 6

def build_keras_model():
    model = Sequential()
    ...

    return model

# initializing ssd 
detection_graph, sess = detector_utils.load_inference_graph()
...
with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        K.set_session(sess)
        model = build_keras_model()
        model.compile(
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy])

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while(True):
            _, frame = cap.read()
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            boxes, scores = detector_utils.detect_objects(frame, detection_graph, sess)
            box_image = detector_utils.get_box_image(1, score_thresh, scores, boxes, im_width, im_height, frame)
            detector_utils.draw_box_on_image(1, score_thresh, scores, boxes, im_width, im_height, frame)
                        # this mean a hand was detected
            if box_image is not None:
                box_image = cv2.cvtColor(box_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                box_image = cv2.resize(box_image, (28, 28))
                box_image_exp = np.expand_dims(box_image, 2)
                box_image_exp = np.expand_dims(box_image_exp, 0)
                                # where the convnet makes its prediction
                pred = model.predict(box_image_exp)
                print(np.argmax(pred))

            cv2.imshow('frame', cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
            if box_image is not None:
                cv2.imshow('hand detection', box_image)
            else:
                cv2.imshow('hand detection', np.zeros((28, 28, 1)))

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```